# Disabling access to a servlet using url

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, filter

I have a web application which contains several servlets. I don't want the user to be able to access some of these servlets by entering the url into the address bar. These servlets should only be accessed when the user clicks on certain links on the web page. I think that this can be done using filers but I am not sure if there is a method to know if the servlet was reached by clicking on a link or through the address bar.

Comment: Well, there is a method, but it's not foolproof. You can set the `Referer` header on click of the link and have a filter check this header for each request. The main flaw here is that anyone with the right tool can alter the value of that header and bypass that check.

Answer (score 0):

Call a javascript function your link click and append a path variable "clicked=yes" to the url as shown below.

```
function myFunction(linkClicked){
    var url = linkClicked.getAttribute("href");
    url = url + "?clicked=yes";
    return false;
}

<a href="" name="myLink" onClick="myFunction(this)"></a>
```

then once in your sevlet, check the value of "`clicked`" parameter, if it's null or empty, then you know the url was accessed by typing the url in the address bar.

If the value of `"clicked" is "yes"`, then we know the link was clicked.

Please note that I have not tested this code and there may be some error but you get the idea.

Comment: This still doesn't solve the main problem because if the user enters the url in addition to the "?clicked=yes" and presses enter then he/she will be able to get through.